# What is the best way to handle dozens of partner logos in dark mode?

Tags: website-design, logo

I am preparing a website to look good in dark mode. Some pages have a ton of partner logos that look very bad when in dark mode because they have black text for example. But they use additional colors so inverting with css is not an option. Also reaching out to the partners or googling for an inverted version is not an option. I can only think of putting a white box behind but it doesn't look good. Anyone have another ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You could look at SE's Meta announcement [New colors launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched?cb=1) for many ways to *not* do it:\

Answer (score 1):

Grayscaling the logos may be a solution when there are various colors, specially when you cannot convert all of them into a single color-fill like white or black.

They would look similar, although it may depend on how many are different between each other.

Comment: This is the standard way of handling this situation

Comment: I was able to get everyone on board with grayscaling on dark mode screens using css filters of invert and grayscale and the result looked perfect, and the effort was minimal, only adding a small amount of css at the top. Thanks.